# react-native NFC reader only enables when phone locked

Tags: android, react-native, nfc

I'm using the [react-native-rfid-nfc-scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rfid-nfc-scanner) package to do NFC reading.

I've done a simple init of the module and added a listener.

```
import {NfcRfidScanner} from "react-native-rfid-nfc-scanner";
const scanner = new NfcRfidScanner();
scanner.init();
var listenerCallback = function(x) { console.log('listener:', x); };
var errorCallback = function(e) { console.log('error:', e); };
scanner.addListener('scanningListener', listenerCallback, errorCallback);
console.log('scanner enabled?', scanner.isEnabled());
console.log('device can use scanner??', scanner.getStatus());
```

When I've got the app open on my usb-connected android device, I see this console output:

```
scanner enabled? false
ReactFabric-prod.js:7003 device can use scanner?? waiting
ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14808 Running application "NativeScannerApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":31}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
```

When I lock the screen on the device and then save a change to the file, kicking off a reload via `watchman`, I see this come through in the console:

```
scanner enabled? true
VM33:62 device can use scanner?? ready
index.js:2277 [React Transform HMR] Patching App
```

Why is the NFC reader not enabling when the phone is unlocked and how do I fix this?